# Vagrantfile with multiple vms: need to designate ssh port

Tags: vagrant

I have a situation where I need to specifically designate what port to ssh to for each of my vagrant vms. I've gotten to the point where I am bouncing between several projects, all of which I use vagrant for.

Here is what my Vagrantfile looks like:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define "inspire" do |inspire|
    inspire.vm.box = "hansode/centos-6.6-x86_64"
    inspire.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.2"
  end

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.3"
  end

  config.vm.define "api" do |api|
    api.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    api.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.4"
  end

  config.vm.define "lamp" do |lamp|
    lamp.vm.box = "chef/centos-7.0"
    lamp.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.5"
  end
end
```

The first one I start up is run on `127.0.0.1:2222`, then next is run on 127.0.0.1:2200, and so on. I need to know if there is a feature where I can permanently set this so that `inspire` always runs on port `2001`; `web` always runs on `2002`; `api` always runs on `2003`; and so on. Something like this?

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define "inspire" do |inspire|
    inspire.vm.box = "hansode/centos-6.6-x86_64"
    inspire.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.2"
    inspire.vm.port 2001
  end

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.3"
    web.vm.port 2002
  end

  config.vm.define "api" do |api|
    api.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    api.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.4"
    api.vm.port 2003
  end

  ...

end
```

does that feature exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `machine.vm.port` but `machine.ssh.port`

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define "inspire" do |inspire|
    inspire.vm.box = "hansode/centos-6.6-x86_64"
    inspire.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.2"
    inspire.ssh.port = 2001
  end
```

so you will connect to inspire on port 2001

**EDIT** Although I would have thought the above is working, it appears that there is some [discussion](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3232) and the below would work

```
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port,
    guest: 22,
    host: 2201,
    id: "ssh",
    auto_correct: true
```

`vagrant ssh` will connect to the VM
and to verify that I correctly ssh into the 2201 port :

```
fhenri@machine:~$ ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2201
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:2201 ([127.0.0.1]:2201)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 6d:21:5c:b3:d9:78:c1:d0:77:a9:79:d5:61:51:e5:bb.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Comment: that doesn't work. I get this error: `/home/jeremy/Vagrantfile:13:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)`. I tried putting this line: `inspire.ssh.port = 2001`, and then call `vagrant up inspire` and it just hangs at `inspire: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...`